# Understanding the model in MVC.

Tags: model-view-controller

I've worked with OOP for a while now, and have gotten into the habit of creating classes for 'things', such as person, account, etc. I was coding in Java for this.

Recently I begun to work with MVC (in PHP), and I've come to realise that, contrary to what I originally thought, the model is not like an OOP class - feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that the model is simply an interface between the controller and the database (maybe with data processing - more on this below). My reason for thinking this stems from my recent messing around with the CodeIgniter framework for PHP. CI doesn't allow for instances of models. Rather, it's a singleton pattern, and in most tutorials I've seen, it's used only for database queries and sometimes some static method.

Now, coming from OOP, I've gotten into the habit of having classes where the data is stored and able to be manipulated (an OOP class). My issue is that in MVC, I'm not sure where this takes place, if it does (I initially thought 'class' was synonymous with 'model'). So, I guess what I'm looking for is someone to explain to me:

1. Where does the manipulation of data (business logic) take place? I've read many articles and posts, and it seems some prefer to do it in the controller, and others in the model. Is one of these more correct  than the other in terms of MVC?
2. Where/how do I store data for use within my application, such as that from a database or JSON/XML files returned from an API call? I'm talking things that would usually be attributes in an OOP class. Does this even still take place, or is it straight from the database to the view without being stored in variables in a class?

If you could link me to any guides/sites that may help me to understand this all better, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `M` is a class, `V` is again a class and `C` is also a class.  I think you should read this [book for design patterns](http://www.amazon.in/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/8131700070?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=9737c4c1-9a63-4b05-b17c-51556cf35ff7&kpid=8131700070)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I understand they are all classes, but I'm referring to the structure that is used in classes in OOP, where objects are defined. AFAIK, the classes in MVC are all singletons, and therefore cannot be used to create instances (such as 5 different 'people' instances)

Comment: That looks like 2 questions, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Representing MVC in terms of classes, you can say that:
Model - A class which stores/provides data.
View - A class which provides functionality to display the provided data in a particular fashion.
Controller - A class which controls that how the data is manipulated and passed around.

MVC design is adopted to provide facility to easily replace any of the module (Model/View/Controller) without affecting the other. In most cases, it is the view which gets changed (like same data represented in form of graphs, chats) but other modules must also be made independent of others.

Comment: This answer is too general, and does not address the specific conerns of the poster.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, and you often hear contrary things about how clean and stripped down models should be vs them actually doing everything you'd think they should do. If I were you I'd take a look at data mappers. Tons of people much smarter than I have written on the subject, so please do some research, but I'll see if I can summarize.

The idea is that you separate out your concept of a model into two things. The first is the standard model. This simple becomes a property bag. All it does is have a state that often reflects your database data, or what your database data will be once saved, or however you use it.

The second is a data mapper. This is where you put the heavy-lifting stuff. It's job becomes providing a layer between your pure model, and the database, that's it. It talks to the database, retrieves data specific to your model, and maps it to the model. Or it reads the model, and writes that data to the database. Or it compares the model's data with that of the DB.

What this does is it allows each layer to concern itself with only one thing. The model only has to keep a state, and be aware of its state. Or have some functionality related to the model that does not involve the database or storage. Now the model no longer cares about talking to the database which is hugely freeing! Now if you ever switch to a different database, or you switch to cookies or storing things in files or caching or any other form of persistence, you never need to change your models. All you have to change is the mapping layer that communicates between your models and the DB.